# How to map class to particular row cell in Element UI table based on condition?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

```
<el-table :data="confirmedAppointments" highlight-current-row style="width: 100%">
                  <el-table-column type="index" width="50">
                  </el-table-column>
                  <el-table-column prop='token' label="Token" width="180">
                  </el-table-column>
                  <el-table-column prop='date'  label="Appoint. date" width="180">
                  </el-table-column>
                  <el-table-column prop='ROV' label="ROV" width="180">
                  </el-table-column>
                  <el-table-column prop='speciality' label="Speciality" width="180">
                  </el-table-column>
                  <el-table-column prop='time' label="Appoint. time" width="180">
                  </el-table-column>
                  <el-table-column prop='status' label="Status" class="red" v-bind:class="{ 'green': status == 'Accepted' }">
                  </el-table-column>

              </el-table>
```

I'm using Element UI table component mapped with dynamic data. On the last column, I have status showing Appproved or Rejected text.

So how can I set particular class to particular cell based on the cell value. By default, the class should be red, but when status value is Approved, the class should be green.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not so familiar with element ui, but pretty the same problem I solve by adding row-class-name to el-table

```js
tableRowClassName({ row }) {

    if (row.status === 'Appproved') {
        return 'success-row'
      } else if (row.status === 'Rejected') {
        return 'warning-row'
      }
      return ''
    },
```

```css
  .el-table .warning-row td:last-child {  (or just .el-table td:last-child (as default color))

    background: red;
  }

  .el-table .success-row td:last-child {

    background: green;
  }
```

```html
< el-table :row-class-name="tableRowClassName">
```

Comment: How to change `td:last-child` to another column I desire?

Comment: For example: td:nth-child(2) for second column

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [cell-class-name](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table) table attribute instead of row-class-name. It can access row and column data and row and column indexes.
You should be able to customize classes and therefore style to each individual cell.